# How do you increase the amount of rows that are shown for Sencha Touch 2.0 pickers on phones?

Tags: mobile, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Does anyone know how to increase the amount of rows shown at one instant for date pickers and general pickers in Sencha Touch 2.0?

For example, by default, a [datepicker](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date) shows 3 rows at a time but I would like to show 4.

Comment: Did you mean number of columns?

Comment: No I meant to say rows. On a phone, by default, Sencha pickers only show 3 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently looked into this again and came up with a solution using css ( this will show 5 rows on the picker instead of the normal 3):

```
.x-sheet.x-picker {
  min-height: 305px !important;
}
```

This works in Sencha Touch 2.0.1. The "!important" thing isn't necessary. Just put this css in after everything else.... For my case I have an application.css that is created using sass but I also have an app.css that is applied after that for any tweaks.
I would just set height but it would be overridden by the elements style which looks like this:

```
element.style {
bottom: 0px !important;
height: 220px !important;
left: 0px !important;
right: 0px !important;
z-index: 8 !important;
}
```

So by setting the min-height it will take precedence over height...... I am not sure if this is the best way and I am open to suggestions/improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to your question lies here

- [Sencha Touch Custom Picker Form Field](http://sree.cc/sencha/sencha-touch-custom-picker-form-field)

Comment: There is already a built in xtype for that which allows multiple columns or slots: [Ext.picker.Picker](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.picker.Picker)